# Python3.7 with GNU/Linux and using os.makedirs() - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

```
import os

def create_dir(child_dir_str):

    try:
        pardir = os.path.abspath('static/')
        original_umask  = os.umask(0o777)
        os.makedirs(pardir,exist_ok=True)
        child_dir = os.path.join(pardir,child_dir_str)
        os.makedirs(child_dir,exist_ok=True)
    finally:
        os.umask(original_umask)
        print('static folder created:', os.path.isdir(pardir))
        print('img folder created: ', os.path.isdir(child_dir))

create_dir('img')
```

When I execute the above code I get this error:

```
[pc@pc-pc xfolder]$ python3.7 test.py
static folder created: True
img folder created:  False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    create_dir('img')
  File "test.py", line 10, in create_dir
    os.makedirs(child_dir,exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pc/Desktop/xfolder/static/img'
[pc@pc-pc xfolder]$ ls -l
total 8
d--------- 2 pc pc 4096 ago 27 15:45 static
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc pc  473 ago 27 15:39 test.py
```

Why does python set the permissions for the static folder to "d---------" if on the code I set umask value of the process  to "0o777"? 
 How could I tell python to set the permissions to 777 when creating folders using makedirs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`umask` specifies which permissions to NOT set. You probably want `os.umask(0o000)` instead. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html for more information.